# Draw on Screen with Pen in Real Time

Tags: collaboration

I am looking for the simplest way to make "drawings" while in online meetings (likely using Windows SketchPad) to demonstrate concepts to those watching

My monitors are not touch screen.

I was looking at getting a Wacom Tablet - but it seems like it may be overkill for what I need.

Has anybody found a better solution?

Comment: What about a Wacom Tablet seems overkill?

Comment: Well it is made for artists and designers - I am just drawing super simple shapes and arrow - I was thinking that there might even be a pen something that I could draw on my desk -

Comment: "super simple shapes and arrows" can be drawn by mouse too

Answer (score 0):

You're probably overthinking this. The capabilities of a Wacom tablet are not an impediment to drawing simple shapes.

If cost is an issue, consider a refurbished or used one, possibly even a previous generation.

You can also try other brands. Searching for the general terms "graphics tablet" or "drawing tablet" should bring up some results, but make sure to do some research on driver compatibility if you think you might ever want to use it on another operating system. Also, keep in mind that patents mean that non-Wacom tablets generally require a battery (often AAAA, yes that's four `A`s. Not hard to find online, but might not be carried by your local drugstore).

Another option, if you have a trackpad, is to use one of the capacitive stylii designed for touchscreens. These are the ones with the large, blunt, conductive tip. This is probably one of the cheapest options (you could probably make one with a paperclip, though it might scratch your trackpad), but you'd have to press the mouse button separately, making its use a bit awkward.